# Can not read the property attach of undefined in socket io(error from bin/www)

Tags: javascript, socket.io, nodes

```
app.j
var socket_io    = require( "socket.io" );
var app = express();
var io  = socket_io();
app.io  = io;
var users = require('./routes/users')(io);
users.js
module.exports=function(io){
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { 
console.log('user connected)
})
bin/www
var io= app.io

io.attach(server)
```

I am working on socket.io and getting error

> can not read property of attach of undefined